# How to add to event listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, blur, keydown

I am trying to add two event listeners to a grocery list to learn javascript. I want to add one on keydown for the enter key and one for blur when I click off the input. The problem is when I try and add both it comes up with an error saying the keydown has already been handled with the blur and wont let me do both. This is my code, suggestions and help much appreciated.

Thank you

```
et myList = ["bananas", "milk", "apples", "eggs", "cake"];
const btnAdd = document.querySelector("#addNew");
const output = document.querySelector(".output");
const newItem = document.querySelector("#addItem")
btnAdd.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("clicked");
  if (newItem.value) {
    myList.push(newItem.value);
    newItem.value = "";
  }
  build();
})


window.onload = build;

function build() {
  output.innerHTML = "<h2>My List</h2>";
  const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  for (let i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

    // List
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.ind = i;
    const cell1 = document.createElement("td");
    cell1.innerHTML = myList[i];
    cell1.classList.add("todo" + i);
    row.appendChild(cell1);

    // Checkbox
    const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.classList.add("checkbox" + i);
    checkbox.onchange = crossOut;
    row.appendChild(checkbox);

    function crossOut() {
      let completed = document.querySelector(".todo" + i);
      if (this.checked) {
        completed.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      } else {
        completed.style.textDecoration = "none";
      }
    }



    // delete button
    const cell2 = document.createElement("td");
    const span1 = document.createElement("span");
    span1.innerText = "Delete";
    span1.addEventListener("click", function () {
      //console.log(myList[i]);
      //let temp = this.closest("tr").ind;
      let itemOut = myList.splice(i, 1);
      // This will find what item is at i and remove 1 item
      //console.log(myList);
      build();
    })
    cell2.appendChild(span1);

    // 
    const span2 = document.createElement("span");
    span2.innerText = "Edit";
    span2.addEventListener("click", function () {
      row.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
      let tempEle = row.firstElementChild;
      const newInput = document.createElement("input");
      newInput.value = tempEle.innerText;
      tempEle.innerText = "";
      tempEle.appendChild(newInput);
      newInput.focus();


      newInput.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          tempEle.innerHTML = newInput.value;
          row.style.backgroundColor = "White";
          myList[i] = newInput.value;
        }
      })

      // newInput.addEventListener("blur", function (e) {
      //   tempEle.innerHTML = newInput.value;
      //   row.style.backgroundColor = "White";
      //   myList[i] = newInput.value;
      // })
      // console.log(tempEle);

    })
    cell2.appendChild(span2);
    row.appendChild(cell2)
    tbl.appendChild(row);

  }
  output.appendChild(tbl);


}
```

Comment: can you add the stack trace?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by stack trace? Fairly new to coding and don't yet understand all the lingo

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @TheSynergist I just meant the actual error message

Comment: groceryList.js:77 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/groceryList.js:77:29)
(anonymous) @ groceryList.js:77

Comment: This is when I uncomment the addEventListner( "blur", section

Comment: What actions on the webpage (click, out of focus) causes that error? I think it might have something to do with the fact that you're setting the innerHTML of tempEle to be something else, but you've also got the node as a child of tempEle,  so it actually removes itself, and there is a conflict there.

Comment: Its when I press the return key to enter the edited version the error comes up

Comment: Try adding a e.stopPropagation() at the end of your blur event listener. If it fixes things, then I'll know what the issue was. You can also try adding it to the end of your keydown inside your if statement

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the keydown event listener for when you press the key down, Then you will have to isolate the keyCode for the whichever key. After that you will have to do the same for keyup but use .mouse0 as the keycode
I'm sorry I cant write it out for you but I hope this helps.

Edit:
If you look up how to use keyup, keydown and look up what the key code is you should easily be able to work it out. I've only done it using jquery and not in vanilla JS. Its done basically the same way

Comment: I will have a look now and see if I can make sense of it. Thank you.